# WSO2 - Migrating STORE APIs from One Server to Another Server

Tags: api, wso2, migrate

****WSO2 -  Migrating STORE APIs   from One Server to Another Server****

As of now , I am only  able to migrate PUBLISHER APIS from one Server to Another Server . The  Below  Links gives an understanding of the same

http://sanjeewamalalgoda.blogspot.in/2015/06/how-to-import-export-apis-with-wso2-api.html

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM190/Migrating+the+APIs+to+a+Different+Environment

**PROBLEM** -  Even though , If I migrate my WSO2 PUBLISHER APIs from one Server to Another  Server , Again  I have to do a SUBSCRIPTION with the  WSO2 Store Application and this generates the following
a) Consumer  Key 
b) Consumer  Secret 
c) Token

SINCE , In my  UI Application ,  I am  using the WSO2 STORE URLS , everytime , I migrate my APIs , I need to change the WSO2 URLS in  UI .

**QUESTION** :-  Is there any way , so that only once I need to SUBSCRIBE to the STORE APIS . Later on , In short , UI  Application  should remain unaffected irrespective of  whether we migrate the WSO2 APIMs  or not

Comment: WIth API Import and Export, data related to subscriptions and tokens will not be exchanged. You may do a database migration from one environment to another.

Answer (score 0):

IMO if this is a cluster environment, this has to be resided in axis2.xml. Once you enable clustering class as below example,

e.g.
`<clustering class="org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastClusteringAgent" enable="true">`,

you should add store under `<members>` in cluster.
e.g

```
<members>
<member>
    <hostName>IP of Store</hostName>
    <port>[localMemberPort of Store]</port>
</member>
```

then, when you do changes to a publisher when enabling cluster and if you have registered store members under a publisher, relevant caching refresh notification sent to the store node and the process will carry out by clustering agent.

Hope this information will help you.